# Ember-Data how to know when an entity is fetched

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the best way to know when an entity has been retrieved from the remote store in ember-data?

I need to make a call to retrieve data but I need some values from a fetched ember-data object.

At the moment I am using this approach but I am sure there is a better way.

```
contactLoaded: function(){
  if(!this.getPath('contact.isLoaded')){
    return;
  }

  //make call
}.observes('App.contact.isLoaded')
```

Answer (score 3):

I am fearing it is the only way to achieve your goal, as of today... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
model.one('didLoad', function() {
   alert("I LOADED!";
});
```

Substitute didLoad with didCreate, didUpdate, etc., depending on the async event you're looking for.

`one` will watch the object for the `didLoad` event to fire and won't fire more than once. Use `on` to keep watching.